# Adding a new custom Task field for Salesforce1

Tags: tasks

I have created a new field "Area Covered" . I have added it to the Page Layout . But while checking it in Salesforce1 , I am not able to see that .

Where else do I need to add that?

Comment: FLS is set properly?

Comment: Yes . FLS is set